# How to fill dataframe column as tuple of other columns values using np.where?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a dataframe as follows

```
   id Domain City
   1   DM    Pune
   2   VS    Delhi
```

I want to create a new column which will contain tuple of column values id & Domain,
e.g

```
   id  Domain  City   New_Col
   1   DM      Pune    (1,DM)
   2   VS     Delhi    (2,VS)
```

I know I can create it easily using apply & lambda as follows:

```
df['New_Col'] = df.apply(lambda r:tuple(r[bkeys]),axis=1)     ##here bkeys = ['id','Domain']
```

However I this takes hell lot of time for larger dataframes having > 100k records. Hence I want to use np.where like this

```
df['New_Col'] = np.where(True, tuple(df[bkeys]), '')
```

But this doesn't work, it gives values like: ('id','Domain')

Any suggestions?

Comment: `np.where` does not iterate over the rows of the dataframe or series.  It's a python function, which means that the interpreter evaluates `tuple(df[bkeys])`, and passes that to `where`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.assign(new_col = df[['id','Domain']].agg(tuple, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   id Domain   City  new_col
0   1     DM   Pune  (1, DM)
1   2     VS  Delhi  (2, VS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something or other is giving people a wrong idea of what `np.where` does.  I've seen similar error in other questions.

Let's make your dataframe:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'DM','Pune'],[2,'VS','Delhi']],columns=['id','Domain','City']) 
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   id Domain   City
0   1     DM   Pune
1   2     VS  Delhi
```

Your `apply` expression:

```
In [5]: bkeys = ['id','Domain']
In [6]: df.apply(lambda r:tuple(r[bkeys]),axis=1)
Out[6]: 
0    (1, DM)
1    (2, VS)
dtype: object
```

what's happening here?  `apply` is iterating on the rows of `df`. `r` is one row.

So the first row:

```
In [9]: df.iloc[0]
Out[9]: 
id           1
Domain      DM
City      Pune
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

index with `bkeys`:

```
In [10]: df.iloc[0][bkeys]
Out[10]: 
id         1
Domain    DM
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

and make a tuple from that:

```
In [11]: tuple(df.iloc[0][bkeys])
Out[11]: (1, 'DM')
```

But what do we get when indexing the whole dataframe:

```
In [12]: df[bkeys]
Out[12]: 
   id Domain
0   1     DM
1   2     VS

In [15]: tuple(df[bkeys])
Out[15]: ('id', 'Domain')
```

`np.where` is a function; it is not an iterator.  The interpreter evaluates each of its arguments, and passes them to the function.

```
In [16]: np.where(True, tuple(df[bkeys]), '')
Out[16]: array(['id', 'Domain'], dtype='<U6')
```

This is what you tried to assign to the new column.

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   id Domain   City New_Col
0   1     DM   Pune      id
1   2     VS  Delhi  Domain
```

This assignment only works because the tuple has 2 elements, and `df` has 2 rows.  Otherwise you'd get an error.

`np.where` is not a magical way of speeding up a dataframe `apply`.  It's a way of creating an array of values, which, if the right size can be assigned to a dataframe column (series).

We could create a numpy array from the selected columns:

```
In [31]: df[bkeys].to_numpy()
Out[31]: 
array([[1, 'DM'],
       [2, 'VS']], dtype=object)
```

and from that get a list of lists, and assign that to a new column:

```
In [32]: df[bkeys].to_numpy().tolist()
Out[32]: [[1, 'DM'], [2, 'VS']]
In [33]: df['New_Col'] = _
In [34]: df
Out[34]: 
   id Domain   City  New_Col
0   1     DM   Pune  [1, DM]
1   2     VS  Delhi  [2, VS]
```

If you really want tuples, the sublists will have to be converted:

```
In [35]: [tuple(i) for i in df[bkeys].to_numpy().tolist()]
Out[35]: [(1, 'DM'), (2, 'VS')]
```

Another way of making a list of tuples (which works because array `records` display as tuples:

```
In [42]: df[bkeys].to_records(index=False).tolist()
Out[42]: [(1, 'DM'), (2, 'VS')]
```